# random div on page load

Tags: javascript, math, random, rotation

I am trying to randomize the hero content of a home page. I have this simple code, but it affects all the divs on the page, and I only want it to affect a few.

```
var elems = $("div");
if (elems.length) {
var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
if (i !== keep) {
  $(elems[i]).hide();
}
}
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="hero1">One</div>

<div id="hero2">Two</div>

<div id="hero3">Three</div>

<div id="constant">This content does not rotate.</div>
```

There is another caveat to this, I need it to work within a crappy CMS that strips out my class tags. So it has to be a solution that identifies the divs based on id.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var elems = $('div').not('#constant')
```

?

The [not function](http://api.jquery.com/not/) removes matching elements from the set it's called on.